# Ruby on Rails, ActiveRecord, Postgres, UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT encodings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, encoding

Weirdest error, who’s up for a challenge to try and help me? Spent hours yesterday on it and it’s like magic. I can't believe this is happening and it's driving me crazy.

Btw, using:

- Rails 4.2.3
- Ruby 2.2.3
- pg 0.18
- `Encoding.default_internal = Encoding.default_external = UTF-8`
- `config.encoding = 'utf-8'`

It has to do with Postgres, ActiveRecord and Encodings!
Turns out that we’ve been getting these errors whenever we create new Users on the database with special characters:

`Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8`

`\xC3` may vary depending on the characters. The weird part is that we’ve set since the beginning EVERYTHING to UTF-8. So it really makes no sense and I digged into it, and used this script:

```
User.all.each do
  |user| user.attributes.each do
    |name, value| if value.is_a? String
      puts user.email + name.encoding.to_s + value.encoding.to_s
    end
  end
end
```

And this is the output of one of the users, but all users get the same:

```
dr_lottahelp@blahblah.comUTF-8UTF-8
dr_lottahelp@blahblah.comUTF-8ASCII-8BIT
dr_lottahelp@blahblah.comUTF-8ASCII-8BIT
dr_lottahelp@blahblah.comUTF-8ASCII-8BIT
dr_lottahelp@blahblah.comUTF-8UTF-8
dr_lottahelp@blahblah.comUTF-8UTF-8
dr_lottahelp@blahblah.comUTF-8UTF-8
dr_lottahelp@blahblah.comUTF-8UTF-8
dr_lottahelp@blahblah.comUTF-8UTF-8
dr_lottahelp@blahblah.comUTF-8UTF-8
dr_lottahelp@blahblah.comUTF-8UTF-8
```

Turns out that only 3 fields get the ASCII-8BIT encoding. Which absolutely makes no sense to me!

(Those fields btw, `first_name`, `middle_name`, `last_name`, are exactly the same in the database as the other text fields that got listed on the output, they don't get any special treatment).

Another funny thing is that if I don't fill any of those fields, the encoding is `UTF-8` for the value. But once I fill it, even if I don't use special characters it will get converted to `ASCII-8BIT`.

Any suggestions? I've tried every single thing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so in my case it had to do with the gem `crypt_keeper`.
If you are using special Unicode characters such as `´`, you have to explicitly tell the gem to use UTF-8 to encode, otherwise it will store the values on your database as ASCII-8BIT.

Wish I got a better error message to know it was caused because of that, hopefully someone with the same problem will see this someday!

Comment: Having a very similar issue here. How do you "explicitly tell the gem to use UTF-8 to encode"? I still didn't find root of the issue though...

Comment: I am that someone...I was fighting this problem and stumbled across your post here. Thanks for sharing!